# How to select all items in column by column name getJSON and php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a getJSON call to a php function that returns all items in a column by the column name. This is the PHP function.

```
public function getCertsByCategory($certCategory) {
       $connection = $this -> connect();
       return $this -> select("select '.$certCatogory.' from cert_catalog");
    }
```

This is the function to get the data:

```
function CertName(certCategory) {
       $('#certificationName').empty();
       console.log(certCategory);
       $.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'getCertsByCategory', certCategory: certCategory }, function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
             console.log(value);
             $('#certificationName').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
          });
       });
     }
```

Why am I getting back two dots for the values? This is what it looks like in chrome developer tools.

```
10: Object
..: ".."
__proto__: Object
11: Object
..: ".."
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: My guess why you are getting back 2 dots is your query -> `select '.$certCatogory.' from cert_catalog`. Because you are using single quotes around `.$certCatogory.` you are getting the string literal `.$certCatogory.`. And it looks like `$certCatogory` is empty, so basically you are doing the query `select '..' from cert_catalog`, which would return `".."`. Where are you calling `function getCertsByCategory()`? Are you doing `getCertsByCategory($_GET['certCategory'])`? Also, in your query change the single quotes to backticks and remove the dots -> `select \`$certCatogory\` from cert_catalog`.

Comment: Just notice - you are defining `$certCategory` in `public function getCertsByCategory($certCategory) {`, but calling `$certCatogory` in `return $this -> select("select '.$certCatogory.' from cert_catalog");`. Where `$certCategory` != `$certCatogory`. Try changing your query to `return $this -> select("select \`$certCategory\` from cert_catalog");`